# Conflict with runner dependencies in Beam

Tags: java, maven, apache-flink, apache-beam, apache-samza

I want to test different stream processing engines using Beam, but can't run the program when Flink **and** Samza dependencies are included. If only **one** of them is included, it works fine for all the other runners.

My `pom.xml` contains the following:

```xml
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>1.11</maven.compiler.release>
        <beam.version>2.20.0</beam.version>
        <flink.version>1.9</flink.version>
        <samza.version>1.4.0</samza.version>
        <spark.version>2.4.5</spark.version>
        <jackson.version>2.10.2</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Beam dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Flink dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-flink-${flink.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Samza dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-samza</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
            <artifactId>samza-api</artifactId>
            <version>${samza.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
            <artifactId>samza-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${samza.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
            <artifactId>samza-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${samza.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
            <artifactId>samza-kv_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${samza.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.samza</groupId>
            <artifactId>samza-kv-rocksdb_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${samza.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spark dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-spark</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- additional dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The error message thrown when trying to execute `PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).create();` is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: methods with same signature getMaxBundleSize() but incompatible return types: long and others
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ProxyGenerator.checkReturnTypes(ProxyGenerator.java:657)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ProxyGenerator.generateClassFile(ProxyGenerator.java:462)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ProxyGenerator.generateProxyClass(ProxyGenerator.java:338)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.defineProxyClass(Proxy.java:535)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.build(Proxy.java:648)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.lambda$getProxyConstructor$1(Proxy.java:426)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue$Memoizer.get(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:329)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue.computeIfAbsent(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:205)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyConstructor(Proxy.java:424)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass(Proxy.java:384)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Cache.validateWellFormed(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1898)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Cache.validateWellFormed(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1842)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Cache.register(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1837)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Cache.initializeRegistry(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1825)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Cache.<init>(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1817)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Cache.<init>(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1786)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.resetCache(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:542)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.<clinit>(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:508)
    ... 1 more
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug. I filed [BEAM-9830](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9830) to track it, and it should be resolved in a future release. In the meantime, you can split your application by runner, since Beam is not really designed to use multiple runners within the same pipeline.